# Trouble with C pointers

Tags: c, pointers

Here's the deal. I have a large character array and am trying to manipulate it. Here's some code I was using to test the idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char r[65536],*e=r;

main() {
    e+=8;
    while(*e) {
        *e+=1;
        e+=5;
        *e-=1;
        e-=1;
    }
    *e+=1;
    printf("%i",*e);
    printf(" %c",e);
}
```

What it's supposed to do is:

1. Set the first element to 8
2. Then, while the current element is not zero,

   1. Move to the next cell
   2. Add 5 to it
   3. Move back
   4. Subtract one. (This repeats 8 times because the while test will fail when it has subtracted the last one)
3. Display the location of the pointer
4. Display the contents of the array that the pointer points to (I hope)

What it does:

```
1 Φ
```

as opposed to

```
40 (
```

^^ 8 x 5 = 40, so that's what it should display.

Any tips/suggestions/criticism accepted.

Comment: you almost got it but when you define a pointer with *e you dont need to refer to it as *e just e and that gives you the memory address of the pointer. When you *e it again like with the *e += 8 you are dereferencing it and adding 8 to the ASCII value char that was there making it some other char.

Comment: Note that `main` should return an `int` (normally 0).

Comment: You should also initialize your array. There is no guarantee that *e is 8 after `*e+=8;`

Comment: @user606723: There is a guarantee. Only automatic variables (non-static "locals") are not automatically initialized.

Comment: global variables are initialized? You learn something new everyday.

Comment: @user606723: "If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then [...] it is initialized to [...] zero [...]" (9899-1990, 6.7.8, §10). See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're dereferencing ***exactly*** where you should ***not*** and vice versa. What you meant to do was:

```
*e+=8;
while(*e) {
    e+=1;
    *e+=5;
    e-=1;
    *e-=1;
}
*e+=1;
printf("%d",e - r); //index
printf(" %p",e); //pointer value      
printf(" %c",*e); //pointee value
```

`*` retrieves the value the pointer points to.

Comment: Not "exactly". The control condition of the `while` is correct.

Answer (score 7):

"Set the first element to 8" would be

```
*e = 8;
```

"Move to the next cell" would be

```
e += 1;
```

and so on.

With `e` you are accessing the pointer, the address. Incrementing/decrementing it will move the pointer forth and back.

With `*e` you access the value it is pointing to (dereference it).

You are using it the other way around most of the times.

**Remark**: Note that in the declaration of `e` you have to write `char *e = r;` to initialize the pointer (not the value). Here the `*` specifies the type of `e`. The declaration reads: `e` is a pointer to `char` and its value is (the address of) `e` --- it is similar to `char *r; r = e;`.

Comment: So, `*e` instead of `e`? I'm really confused. Does the * part refer to the value or the location? EDIT: It works, I switched out all `*e`s with `e`s and vice versa. Thanks!

Comment: `e` is the location. `*e` is the value.

Answer (score 6):

`*e` *dereferences* the pointer; that is, it manipulates the value pointed to. Manipulating the pointer itself means manipulating `e` directly.

When you do `e+=5`, you're moving the pointer ahead by 5 spaces, if you do `*e+=5`, then you add 5 to the value pointed to by the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand pointer arithmetic and dereference.

`*e` is used to access what `e` points to, so `*e += 1` increases the value of what `e` points to, not goes to the next address. Also, `e += 8` increases the actual pointer, and `e` will now point at the ninth entry in the array.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing your dereferencing.  The `*` operator when calling the pointer gives you the data stored at the location.  Without it gives you the address.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution :

```
#include <stdio.h>

char  r[65536];
char* e = r;

main() {
    *e = 8;
    while(*e) {
        e++;
        *e+=5;
        e--;
        *e-=1;
    }
    e++;
    printf("position : %i\n",e-r);
    printf("value : %c\n",*e);
}
```

You simply mixed * and &.

If **P** is a pointer, then *P is the value pointed by the pointer.
If **V** is a value, then &V is the address where the value is stored.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char r[65536], *e=r;

int main()
{
    *e = 8;
    while (*e) {
        e++;
        *e += 5;
        e--;
        *e -= 1;
    }
    e++;
    printf("%p %c\n", e, *e);
    return 0;
}
```